# How can I record with an external camera on Android

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to make a "simple" app that has only one button. There will be a "REC" button in the center of the screen. When the REC button is tapped, I would like to have an external camera to start recording and when the button is tapped again, the camera stops recording and the video is uploaded to a server. The camera could be something like a GoPro or any other external camera. Does anyone know if this would be possible? I have been looking online all day and have not found anything for this.

Comment: Not sure where you have been searching as this post has some leads: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10795/is-it-possible-to-control-gopro-recording-without-the-official-app

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the phone's internal camera to record the video and get back the file when recording is complete. For making use of android's camera you need to send out and intent like this

```
private static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 4;
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
     startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
}
```

You can receive it's result by overriding the onActivityResult method like this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        switch (requestCode){
           Uri videoUri = data.getData();
           //Do something with the video
        }
```